# Addressing The specified type member Date is not supported in LINQ to Entities exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In the bellow linq query i'm getting the following exception:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties
>   are supported.

**Query:**

```
var query = db.Cases
    .Where(
        dateInterval.Equals( ControlValues.Today )? DbFunctions.TruncateTime( c.EffectiveDate.Date ).Value.Day == currentDayNum :
                            dateInterval.Equals(ControlValues.CurrentWeek) ? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                                DbFunctions.TruncateTime( c.EffectiveDate.Date ).Value, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,DayOfWeek.Monday)  == currentWeekNum :
                            dateInterval.Equals(ControlValues.NextWeek) ? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                                DbFunctions.AddDays( DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.EffectiveDate.Date), 7 ).Value, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday ) == nextWeekNum :
                            dateInterval.Equals(ControlValues.CurrentMonth) ? DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.EffectiveDate.Date).Value.Month == currentMonthNum : true)
```

As you can see from code i'm already using ***DbFunctions.TruncateTime*** function in the query,neverthe less the exception still hopping. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any of your `DateTime` objects in your LINQ query, just use the object, not the `Date` Member, like this:  `c.EffectiveDate`.

EF can't translate the Date property to T-SQL, which is why it is running into problems.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, that was the problem here. Now i'm getting a different issue with the same query, i have opened a new question, please review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487641/extracting-week-number-from-datetime-value-in-linq-to-entity-query