# Extracting Week number from DateTime value in Linq to entity query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In the bellow query i'm getting the following exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   GetWeekOfYear(System.DateTime, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule,
>   System.DayOfWeek)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.
>
> Query:

```
        var query = db.Cases
            .Where(c => c.UserID == userId
                && ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( dateInterval ) || dateInterval.Equals( ControlValues.Today )? 
                    DbFunctions.TruncateTime( c.EffectiveDate ).Value.Day == currentDayNum :
                    dateInterval.Equals(ControlValues.CurrentWeek) ?
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime( c.EffectiveDate ).Value, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,DayOfWeek.Monday)  == currentWeekNum :
                            dateInterval.Equals(ControlValues.NextWeek) ?
                                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                                    DbFunctions.AddDays( DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.EffectiveDate), 7 ).Value, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday ) == nextWeekNum :
                                        dateInterval.Equals(ControlValues.CurrentMonth) ?
                                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.EffectiveDate).Value.Month == currentMonthNum :
                                            true)
```

Question in short, is there a way to extract the week of the year number from a database value in linq queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SqlFunctions.DatePart` static method. It will be transformed into `DATEPART` SQL function call in generated SQL query:

> [**`SqlFunctions.DatePart` Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> Returns an integer that represents the specified datepart of the specified date.
>
> This function is translated to a corresponding function in the
>   database. For information about the corresponding SQL Server function,
>   see DATEPART (Transact-SQL).

To get week number, use `"week"` as parameter.